# Sagemaker XG-Boost (objective=reg:logistic) not working on highly imbalanced data set

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

I'm working on credit fraud data set on AWS Sagemaker. The data set is highly imbalanced. It has only 0.1732% fraudulent transactions. I want to predict a given transaction as fraudulent(1) or not(0) using XG-Boost from sagemaker. When I set the objective function in hyperparameter as 'multi:softmax' and number of classes = 2, It is giving good results with recall of 85%. When I set the objective function as 'reg:logistic', my recall is getting to 0. It is just labeling every transaction as non-fraudulent. Shouldn't logistic and multi-softmax for 2 classes give the same answer? Also, is there any hyperparameter whose default value should be changed while dealing with imbalanced data sets?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First thing for imbalanced dataset, is to ensure over-representation of minority label examples. XGBoost has a provision for this using the argument `scale_pos_weight`.

Please refer to argument `scale_pos_weight` details at 
https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html